# Resources for advanced LCDS topics?

Tags: java, apache-flex, lcds

I'm looking to bone up my LCDS knowledge, but find that resources for anything beyond simple examples is lacking.

I'd appreciate if anyone could share sites and/or training courses they can reccommend that cover things like:

- NIO configuration on LCDS
- Configuring LCDS as an Edge server
- Configuring LCDS in a cluster, and appropriate fail-over strategies
- Advanced assemblers
- Strategies for managing high-throughput applications
- Advanced JMS integration

Comment: Adobe don't tend to make this info publicly available as they'd rather you took out a hugely expensive support contract instead. If you can afford LCDS, you can afford the support!

Answer (score 1):

Marty, before starting to use it in production I recommend to understand the product and its benefits and to see if the problem that you are trying to resolve really needs it. The best source of information is the developer guide..I agree that you cannot find too much advanced topics about your questions. You can find bits of info however on some blogs like coenraets.org,
dcooper.org, meteatamel.wordpress.com.